# How does BackgroundWorker work with ports

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'd like to ask about how exactly the BackgroundWorker works. I have two tasks:

- Create a receipt and print it using a fiscal printer
- Save the receipt to a database

For some reason, it seems like it sometimes doesn't work and BackgroundWorker doesn't finish (or cannot close fiscal priter port).

Code:

```
BackgroundWorker bw2 = new BackgroundWorker();
bw2.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
{
    bool result = printReceipt.print(parameters);

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnString)
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DECLARE @token uniqueidentifier; " +
                                                                   "EXEC usp_AsyncExecInvoke @procedureName = N'CreateDocument' " (...)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("printed", result == true ? 1 : 0);
        (...)
    }
}
```

In printRceipt.print there is method which opens the port, prints the receipt and closes the port. As I said, for some reason, sometimes (maybe when procedure took too long?) it doesn't complete these tasks. Eventually the port goes into a 'sleep' state (or something like that) and I need to restart the application.

What would be best way to do this? Maybe I should use two BackgroundWorkers (the first to print, the second to save to the DB - but how do I capture my boolean result value then?)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Probably typo - `using`.

Comment: Don't close the port.  The MSDN article for SerialPort.Close() specifically warns about this.  Also quite easy to trigger deadlock if the DataReceived event handler is using Invoke().  Your snippet is quite inadequate.

Comment: Please, format your question, remove typo's and format code to look "attractive".

Comment: Can you put in some logging (like log4net) to help trace and see that a) function gets called, b) trace through print call, c) trace through sql call.  This will at least help narrow down where the problem may be.

Comment: Code is not actually important. I just rather wanted to explain what I'm exactly doing - first print receipt then save to db using stored procedure.

Comment: @user13657 And we're telling you that the code *is* important.  If you aren't willing to provide enough to diagnose the problem, then we can't help you.

Comment: Your problem seems to be on the print method. If you don't provide us the code, we cant help you, sorry.